# Pylint shows errors even though there are none

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask-sqlalchemy, pylint

I have some code as follows:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

**code for initializing app**

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

class course(db.Model):
    __name__ = 'course'
    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement= True, primary_key= True)

** more code **
```

I dont receive any errors when i run the code and everything works as expected, but pylint throws errors as:-

```
Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' member
Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Integer' member
Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'String' member
```

Is there anyway to fix these, as these errors are clearly not there in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the right pylint plugin for that : https://pypi.org/project/pylint-flask-sqlalchemy/